# Datas for report from mysql table

Tags: mysql

I am Creating a report for my website where I would be listing property prices at various 
locations.I have a table like below

```
 CREATE TABLE report(report_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
                     Locations VARCHAR(255),
                     date VARCHAR(255),
                     ratepersqft INT);
```

I have values in table as Below

```
 INSERT INTO report(Locations, date, ratepersqft)
             VALUES('Location A', '2012-01-16', 2500),
                   ('Location B', '2012-01-21', 1750),
                   ('Location C', '2012-01-20', 1650),
                   ('Location C', '2012-02-19', 2100),
                   ('Location A', '2012-02-18', 2560),
                   ('Location B', '2012-02-12', 1790),
                   ('Location C', '2012-03-04', 2250),
                   ('Location A', '2012-03-25', 2680),
                   ('Location B', '2012-03-05', 2540),
                   ('Location A', '2012-08-21', 2870),
                   ('Location C', '2012-09-12', 2150),
                   ('Location B', '2012-10-18', 2760);
```

**Location           |     Month          |     RatePerSqFt**

```
 Location A     Jan              2500
 Location A     Feb              2560
 Location A     March            2680
 Location A     August           2870
 Location A     sept             2870
 Location A     oct              2870

 Location B     Jan              1750      
 Location B     Feb              1790  
 Location B     March            2540
 Location B     August           2540
 Location B     sept             2540
 Location B     oct              2760    

 Location C     Jan              1650      
 Location C     Feb              2100  
 Location C     March            2250
 Location C     August           2250
 Location C     sept             2250
 Location C     oct              2760
```

I want to plot values for all possible datas available in table. If you see table Location A does not have any entry for month October.But Since Location B has entry for October I want a entry in output table with the rate of last registered month August for location A.

So it is showing as 2870.

Similarly for location B has no entry for august.but Since Location A has rate for August month I am bringing Location B and populating with last month rate that is 2540.

The same for C.

How to write a query or proc for the above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Here is [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/79dd6/19)

```
select Locations,year,month,
(select ratepersqft from report where 
        Locations=tl.locations
        and
        DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y%m')<=tp.monthNum
        order by DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y%m') desc
        limit 1) as t
       from
(select distinct Locations from report) tl,
(select distinct YEAR(date) year,
                 MONTHName(date) month,
                 DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y%m') monthNum
                 from report) tp

order by Locations,monthNum
```

Comment: Wow Worked like charm But its is showing month as excluded any idea

Answer (score 0):

looks like grouping is what you're looking for

```
SELECT Locations, date_format(date,'%b') as month, sum(ratepersqft) as rates 
FROM report GROUP BY Locations, month(date);
```

I'm not sure about `sum`. May be it should be `avg` or something else.

Comment: Thanks so much for reply.I think my question was not clear to you. There are 6 distinct months that belong to different location as a whole. So i want a entry for rate per sqft in output table which points to the month before even the location does not have entry for that particular month

Comment: location A does not have entry for sept and oct. But since oct is in Location B and sept in Location C I am populating the sept and oct for location A in output table with the last month value that is August 2870